# Difference between create or calling class in ORM

Tags: python, django-models

Suppose I have a class named Dude in django model.

```
class Dude(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I can create an instance of Person in the DB either by calling `Dude.objects.create(name='Pepe')` or `Dude(name='Pepe')`.

My question is what is the difference and what method is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one creates the object in the db first and then you can use it.

With `Dude(name='Pepe')` you get an object that is not in db before you call `.save()`

If your model has many required fields you have to include all in the `.create()` call.. otherwise it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

The line `Dude.objects.create(name='Pepe')` creates the object in the DB and returns it. You can see that it was already saved in the DB by inspecting its `pk`:

```
>>> obj = Dude.objects.create(name='Pepe')
>>> obj.pk
1
```

The line `Dude(name='Pepe')` creates the object in memory, but does not save to database yet:

```
>>> obj = Dude(name='Pepe')
>>> obj.pk                       # will be 'None'
>>> obj.save()
>>> obj.pk
1
```